# Swift 3.1 Get a range between two char?

Tags: swift

I am clearly doing something wrong, because this has newer taken me so long to do the following:(Playground code beneath).

Note: Swift 3.1 ~

I am just trying to get `123` out from `piz(123)zazz`

```
let aString = "piz(123)zazz"

let startBracket: Character = "("
if let idx1 = aString.characters.index(of: startBracket) {
    let pos1 = aString.characters.distance(from: aString.startIndex, to: idx1)
    print("Found \(startBracket) at position \(pos1)")
}
else {
    print("Not found")
}

let endBracket: Character = ")"
if let idx2 = aString.characters.index(of: endBracket) {
    let pos2 = aString.characters.distance(from: aString.startIndex, to: idx2)
    print("Found \(startBracket) at position \(pos2)")
}
else {
    print("Not found")
}

let range = pos1..<pos2 // << this is not working, I give up!!!

let result_1 = aString.substring(with: range)
```

Comment: you should be doing it at the string, not the characters. Get the rangeOfString upper or lower bound and create your range with that

Comment: For the sake of future readers of this thread, please don't vandalize the question after receiving answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's much easier:

- The start index is the `upperBound` of the range of `(` in the string
- The end index is the `lowerBound` of the range of `)` in the string

  ```
    let aString = "piz(123)zazz"

    if let openParenthesisRange = aString.range(of: "("),
        let closeParenthesisRange = aString.range(of: ")", range: openParenthesisRange.upperBound..<aString.endIndex) {

        let range = openParenthesisRange.upperBound..<closeParenthesisRange.lowerBound
        let result = aString.substring(with: range)
        print(result)
    }
    else {
        print("Not found")
    }
  ```

---

Alternatively regular expression, it's more code but it's much more versatile

```
let string = "piz(123)zazz"

let pattern = #"\((\d+)\)"# // searches for 0 ore more digits between parentheses

do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
    if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: string, range: NSRange(string.startIndex..., in: string)) {
        let range = match.rangeAt(1)
        let start = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location)
        let end = string.index(start, offsetBy: range.length)
        print(string.substring(with: start..<end))
    } else {
        print("Not Found")
    }
} catch {
    print("Regex Error:", error)
}
```

Comment: `if let start = aString.range(of: "(")?.upperBound,
let end = aString.range(of: ")", range: start..<aString.endIndex)?.lowerBound,
    start != end {
    let result = aString[start..<end]
}`

Comment: you can use the openParenthesisRange upperboud as the startIndex for the second rangeOfString range. this way you will search only the substring left. no need to search from the beginning of the string

Answer (score 3):

Your `pos1` and `pos2` are out of scope when you are trying to use. They both have been defined inside of an `if` block and their scope ends there itself.

I would suggest declaring them on the top to have them in scope.

```
 let aString = "piz(123)zazz"
 let pos1: Int?  // You don't need optional here but I prefer it 
 let pos2: Int? 
 .
 .
 .
 if let p1 = pos1, p2 = pos2  { // Optional Chaining
     let range = pos1..<pos2
 }
```